# What's the best way to consume a web service that exposes typed objects when all data I have is in SOAP XML format?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

I am trying to consume a web service, so I've added a service ref in Visual Studio which generated a proxy with typed objects (data contracts).

The challenge I am facing is that the data I want to send down the channel is already serialized as SOAP XML and contains all the SOAP headers!! Is there a way to transmit this SOAP XML down the channel by-passing converting it to typed objects and letting WCF auto Serialize it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your serialized XML is from the same webservice as the one you added a service reference to in visual studio, you should be able to use an XmlSerializer to deserialize your XML into the typed objects from the web service reference.

Optionally, you can create your web reference in visual studio so that it doesn't create the typed objects.  There are two types of references, Service Reference, and Web Reference.  One or the other (can't remember which) should allow you to operate against the webservice with xml instead of typed objects.

Optionally again, you could try using the SoapHttpClientProtocol "[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)" to call it yourself (which is what the typed client's derrive from).  It has methods like BeginInvoke which allow you to call a web service method by name etc.

Comment: I'd rather NOT have to deserialize the XMLs because I get them already formatted as SOAP envelops and ready for transmission. Ideally, I'd rather send them as is without having to modify them.

Comment: I read this article on SoapHttpClientProtocol:  http://orbinary.com/blog/2010/01/getting-the-raw-soap-xml-sent-via-soaphttpclientprotocol/ 

My generated client class howerver, doesn't derive from SoapHttpClientProtocol!! I am using .net 4.5.

Comment: I found SoapExtension class which looks promissing...reading on it!